# How to access the equalizer in iTunes 11?

Tags: itunes

How do you access the equalizer in iTunes 11?  Or is just gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Opt-Cmd-2</kbd> or via the Window menu

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to get it to show up on PC: <kbd>Ctrl-Shift 2</kbd>